# Using variable/function before it is declared

Tags: f#

I have a recursion that I can't resolve:

```
module Test
type Command = 
    | Exit of string
    | Action of string * (unit -> unit)

let getName command = 
    match command with
    | Exit(n) -> n
    | Action(n, _) -> n

let listCommands commands = 
    List.iter (getName >> printf "%s\n") commands

let hello () = 
    printf "Well, hi\n"

let help () = 
    printf "Available commands are:\n"
    listCommands commands // <- ERROR IS HERE!!!, F# doesn't know of commands array

let commands = [
    Exit("exit")
    Action("hello", hello)
    Action("help", fun() -> help)
]

listCommands commands // just some command to make module compile
```

In method `help()` I use list `commands`, which, in turn, references method `help()`. How do I nicely break this recursion? I can do mutable and so on, but that's not a functional style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `let rec ... and` construct:

```
let rec help () = 
    printf "Available commands are:\n"
    listCommands commands
and commands = [
    Exit("exit")
    Action("hello", hello)
    Action("help", help)
]
```